# Ubuntu 18.04.1 - System settings after removing network-manager and installing wicd

Tags: wireless, network-manager, system-settings, wicd, gnome-control-center

I've been having some issues with my wireless connection for some time, even in Ubuntu 16.04
A couple of weeks ago I finally switched to the new Ubuntu version and I still had the same problems, my connection would disconnect and reconnect every now and then, affecting my downloads or processes that required Internet access, and I couldn't see one of my wireless networks, the one I use for printing, when every other device could.
So this morning I removed network-manager and installed wicd, and I can finally see that wireless network I was talking about.
But now the problem is that I can't access the system settings, not even pressing the button at the top right corner.

I read that this could be worked around by installing gnome-control-center, but when I try to do it, it said that I need to install network-manager along with it (dependencies?).
But Network Manager doesn't seem to work with me...

What could I do?

---

Edit:
I've installed gnome-control-center and everything seems back to normal.
I can see the previously unseen wireless network at the Wi-Fi settings tab.
But apparently I now have both network-manager and wicd.
Is that bad?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

gnome-contol-center and Gnome-Shell both integrate with NetworkManager, they do not integrate with wicd.

To use wicd, use the client tools/GUI for wicd (whatever that is).

Installing above gnome components likely has a dependancy on libnm, NetworkManager's client library. That however does not mean, that you need NetworkManager (the daomon) running as well. Or even installed, if installing gnome-contol-center drags in NetworkManager, it seems like a packaging issue. Of course, if you don't have NetworkManager running but wicd, these Gnome GUI components won't do much for networking.

You theoretically can have wicd and NetworkManager running in parallel, as long as they manage different interfaces.